# MPMoviePlayerViewController won't display the end of the clip

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, mp4

Any idea why `MPMoviePlayerViewController` won't play the end of a short movie?
It plays the entire clip but then the video displays a frame a few seconds from the end and stays like that till the end.

No idea where to start.

Fwiw, the clip is on the file system and I am getting an `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification`.

Comment: Try playing the same clip remotely via mobile safari. In case the player within mobile safari behaves the same way, then you can be sure it is not a problem in your code but the encoding (which I actually assume already from what you describe).

Comment: Neat! That was the problem. Somehow, dragging the clip into Xcode changed the file. It changed from an 8.9MB file to an 8.3MB file. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing it using Mobile Safari revealed the problem - movie clip file was corrupt.
Fixed by copying over a new version of the file.